# how to change mimetype for executable text file

Tags: linux, mime-types

I am using linux slitaz 3.0 OS & pcmanfm 0.5.2 file manager.

I have .mplayer/config file on my ext3 partition as

```
$ls -l  ~/.mplayer/config
-rw-r--r--    1 tux      tux            94 Jun 14 20:38 /home/tux/.mplayer/config
```

This file gets opened with gvim by default.
If I copy this file to my ntfs partition it becomes

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           94 Jun 14 20:38 config
```

Now I want to open this by default with gvim .
What should I add in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`?
I have already added

```
application/x-executable=gvim.desktop
```

Yet the first option is Execute while 'open with' submenu has vim,beaver,leafpad in that order.

Comment: Though
'$file config' says
'config: ASCII text'